# Is it possible to show UIView with XIB in UIViewController in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have not precisely asked my question because it is of storyboard and I did not get how do I ask my problem.

I am having one UIViewController within which on button click I want to show some UIView,ScrollView.
Here I didn't go with adding a UIView in my parent ViewController because I may have more Views and I don't want to code the whole thing in same one ViewController and make it Complex for that reason I thought to make individual classes.

For that I have thought to create subClass of UIView and ScrollView and on button click i just Add them as `subview`. With story board I am not getting how to I take XIBs of UIView or ScrollView.

Do I need to take individual ViewController for each UIView or scrollview ? With that I want to manage the graphic which can easily show where the app is going.

Or any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the requirement to show many views in single view as a container.
I create different ViewControllers and used to "Custom" to bind them.

After that i created a class subclassing "UIStoryboardSegue" class.
Where I prepared a method

```
- (void)perform {

    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) [self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dest = (UIViewController *) [self destinationViewController];

   if([src isKindOfClass:[VC class]])
    {
        dest.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 485.0f, 582.0f);
        [src.view addSubview:dest.view];
    }

    [src addChildViewController:dest];

}
```

This adds viewcontroller's view as subview to mainVC and also with different class files so that code does not mess up.

Hope this help...